# R kableExtra 1 column header spanning multiple columns

Tags: r, kableextra

I am making a table using kableExtra package in R.

```
iris2 <- head(iris)
iris2[6] <- NA
kbl(iris2) %>%
kable_classic()
```

[image]

What I want is for "Species" to span both column 5 and 6 (so the column name "V6" is removed"). Something like this (edited photo)...
[image]

How can I accomplish this? I have tried add_header_above() to create a new header which works, but I can't remove the original header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

Hide the original column names and use `add_header_above` to assign the columns as per choice.

```
library(kableExtra)

iris2 <- head(iris)

iris2[6] <- NA
kbl(iris2, col.names = NULL) %>%
  add_header_above(c(names(iris2)[1:4], "Species" = 2)) %>%
  kable_classic()
```

[image]